# Integral $\int \frac{\operatorname d \! x}{\sinh^4 x}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate:

$$\int  \dfrac{\operatorname d \! x}{\sinh^4 x}$$

I tried to split it in $\int \frac{1}{\sinh^2x}\frac{1}{\sinh^2x}$ and then integrate by parts, but it's seems to complicate the whole thing.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}
\int\operatorname{csch}^4{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int\operatorname{csch}^2{x}\left(-1+\coth^2{x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\int\operatorname{csch}^2{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int\coth^2{x}\operatorname{csch}^2{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{\sinh^4 x}dx & =16\int\frac{1}{(e^x-e^{-x})^4} dx 
\end{align}$$
Substitute $u=e^x, du=udx$

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{\sinh^4 x}dx  &=16 \int\frac{1}{u} \cdot \frac{1}{(u-1/u)^4} du  \\
& = 16\int \frac{u^3}{(u^2-1)^4} du
\end{align}$$
Substitute $u^2-1=v, dv=2udu$
$$\int \frac{1}{\sinh^4 x}dx =8\int \frac{v+1}{v^4} dv $$
Now use power law and replace back everything.